# Dots in failed test message

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit3

I'm using Maven and jUnit.

In test I have an assertion

```
assertEquals("3", k.calculateArg("2+1.0"));
```

and I've got error:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: expected:<...> but was:<....0>
```

How can I make Maven to show whole texts? They are not so long to abbreviate.

I use jUnit 3.8.1 (from pom.xml):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you sure,that this is an abbreviation? I think this are the actual values.

Comment: This IS abbreviation. I added line of code with assertion.

Comment: Which JUnit Version do you use? The actual code ( https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/ComparisonFailure.java ) will abbreviate only if the text is longer that 20 chars.

Comment: I use 3.8.1 (added to question).

Comment: wow... will you consider using later version of JUnit?

Comment: JUnit 3 is already very old and I don't believe it is getting updated anymore, and I can expect there are lots of little bugs that are not fixed there.  If you really insist in using JUnit 3, consider using other assertion library like Hamcrest.  I believe the assert message is going to be much clearer.  The assertion is more readable too.  e.g. `assertThat("result", k.calculateArg("2+1.0"), is("3"));`

Comment: Or even better, use fest-assert: `assertThat(k.calculateArg("2+1.0")).isEqualTo("3)`

Comment: For sure I'll go with newer jUnit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like JUnit 3.8.1 will abbreviate *expected* and *actual* strings iterating forwards and backwards and finding the first difference. Only if the differing parts have the same length, ellipsis will not be inserted. The length of the whole *expected* and *actual* strings is not taken into consideration.

As other posters suggested, switching to a newer version of JUnit is advised. The 3.8.1 is more than 10 years old.